# Trying to use AJAX for the first time - modified code from W3Schools does not work

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I was editing the default code from W3Schools, and it doesn't work now. Can someone point out my error and why it will not update the text?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
}

function switchText()
{loadXMLDoc()
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
 }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>
<button type="button" onclick="switchText()">Change Content</button>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need a semicolon after loadXMLDoc() and after you assign the function to the onreadystatechange

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work. Good catch on the semicolons.

Comment: Welcome to programming :) May I suggest you go back to what worked and move forward from there?

Comment: better reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Ajax and why so: http://w3fools.com

Comment: @KevinDTimm is correct. You have a lot of syntax errors. You should look at how to put these into javascript files and run these through a tool like jsLint to validate the code. You also should look at how to use the developer tools in IE and Chrome or Firebug for Firefox...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your var = xmlhttp; is outside of switchText scope and so it's undefined and throws an error.

Try this

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var xmlhttp;
function loadXMLDoc()
{

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
}

function switchText()
{loadXMLDoc();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
 }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>
<button type="button" onclick="switchText()">Change Content</button>

 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue you have is that you have not validated your code, even down to whether you have matching curly braces or not (hint, you do not!)

moving the open and send commands back into the first function and removing the extra curly brace shoudl work.

the below should work :

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var xmlhttp;
function loadXMLDoc()
{

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();

}

function switchText()
{
  loadXMLDoc();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
 }
}
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>
<button type="button" onclick="switchText()">Change Content</button>

 </body>
</html>
```

hope that helps

Olly

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the following line in ajax_object.html file:

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
```

If you run the file with the above line and look at the 'Show Page Source', 
it will be  apparent that the 'Request & Response' header has its 
-- Status and Code --- set to   nothing

[image]

```
So, delete the line and you will get:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <!--script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
 </script-->

    <script>
      function loadXMLDoc()
 {
 var xmlhttp;
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
 {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
 else
 {// code for IE6, IE5
 xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){

 document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

 }
 xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",true);
 xmlhttp.send();
 }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myDiv"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>
</body>
</html>

If you run this code it will output the ajax_info.txt file.
```